# Add New Key Value to Connection.query Result

Tags: node.js

connection.query(sql, userId, function(error, results, fields) 
Above query gives new a record and I'm sending this as response.json.
My Question is can we append new values to results?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can send any JS type through JSON. So after you receive the result, you can append what you want, and send a response.